# How to make star background interact with mouse

Tags: html, css, animation, cursor, css-animations

I am trying to make a mouse animation to interact with my space background, for example like : https://neokcs.com/ if you move your mouse near stars you will see a white line i want something like that if it is possible please give me the code.

Comment: Using the same JS lib that is on reference website github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, [Particle JS](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/). Check out this. There are many variances of background available with the same, you can customise it easily.

Comment: it works but when I add buttons I can't see them, I think the background covered the buttons but I'm not sure please help this is my code :
<input type="button" id="button1" type="submit" style=" background-color:black;height: 45px; width: 150px; color:red;border-radius:10px;"value="Subscribe link" onclick="enableButton2()"  />
</a> <a href="">
<input type="button" id="button2" style="background-color:yellow; height: 45px;width: 225px;color:red;border-radius:10px;"value="Download link (Subscribe to unlock)" disabled />
</a>